Interface method argument without a type - code smell?
I'm thinking about creating an interface method with an argument that can have a mixed type, to act like metadata. I don't know the metadata type upfront, but I know that some kind of it (or something like context) may be required by the external system adapter implementation.
Example in PHP:
interface AdapterInterface
{
    public function someMethod(SomeEntity $entity, mixed $metadata = null): void;
}

class ExternalSystemAdapter implements AdapterInterface
{
    public function someMethod(SomeEntity $entity, mixed $metadata = null): void
    {
        if (! $metadata instanceof MetadataThatAdapterIsAwareOf) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid metadata');
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}

class Service
{
    public function __construct(private readonly AdapterInterface $adapter)
    {
    }

    public function doSomethingWithEntity(SomeEntity $entity, mixed $metadata)
    {
        return $this->adapter->someMethod($entity, $metadata);
    }
}

$service = new Service(new ExternalSystemAdapter());
$service->doSomethingWithEntity(new SomeEntity(), new SomeMeta());

Is this a code smell? Can it be avoided somehow?

"Can it be avoided somehow?" It's hard to say without knowing anything about your project.

At least, if the metadata is always an object, use ?object for the type hint.

Or specify they types you like to accept, like array|string|object|null $metata. Or declare some sort of Metadata-Getter interface to be passed here, through which the data can be requested.

Why not defining an interface for the metadata? Something like AdapterMetaDataInterface, that defines no methods. The $metadata parameter is null or an instance of AdapterMetadataInterface, which could be a value object, that keeps the metadata values.

Using instanceof in code is a potential place of violation of the open-closed principle (OCP). When a new type appears, you will have to write an additional if, thereby changing the ExternalSystemAdapter class.
A possible solution could be to define a MetaData interface and its various implementations. Moreover, adding new implementations in this case will not affect the ExternalSystemAdapter class.
